# why this regular expression does not match

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a question about the following regular expression:

I want to match the following string: `employee Type="entry" id="mmop" location="somewhere"`
using the RE as following:

```
if {[regexp {id=(".*")} $data -> Id]} {
          #do something here
    }
```

but the result I get is `"entry" id="mmop" location="somewhere"`, how to fix it?

Comment: This may be a typo, but it looks like you should be getting `"mmop" location="somewhere"` instead of `"entry" id="mmop" location="somewhere"`? Can you verify?

Comment: If this is really XML — it looks suspiciously like what you'd find inside a pair of `<…>` — use [tdom](http://tdom.github.com/) to parse it. Tdom's a really good XML handling package for Tcl…

Comment: I can not use any other tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `?` after the `*`, or replace `.` with `[^"]`. The problem is caused by the `.*` being greedy, grabbing everything it can while still matching the pattern.

Comment: And to use ungreedy matching, use `.*?` instead.

Comment: do not understand what does .*? means, the .* means match everything even a empty string, what .*? means?

Comment: `.*` means "match as much as possible", `.*?` means "match as little as possible".

Comment: I try to use if {[regexp {id=([^"].*)} $data -> Id]} {
          #do something here
    } but it matches nothing

Comment: You need to keep the quotes around the... okay, never mind, use this and copy it directly: `{id="([^"]*?)"}`

Comment: ok, I also tried that, but how about if we do not use any "*"?

Comment: Then it will only match one character. Just put exactly what I gave you as your regex.

Comment: hi, I tired that, and it works, but I can not use any "*" in the regexp, how to achieve the same but with avoiding the "*"?

Comment: Why? You were perfectly capable of using it in your original attempt... I guess you could just use `+` instead, and that'll match anything except an empty id.